# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError even after if migrations status show all as UP

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm hitting this error even after i do this:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed RAILS_ENV=development
```

I'm running rails 4.2 on OS X with rvm ruby 2.2

Look at my migration status:

```
devhost:dss jony$ rake db:migrate:status RAILS_ENV=development
database: /Users/jony/dev/rails/dss/db/development.sqlite3
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
up     20150119104811  Create tipo contratos
up     20150119104837  Create docentes
up     20150119105018  Create categoria
up     20150119111856  Create ucs
up     20150119113429  Create departamentos
up     20150119113737  Create ano lectivos
up     20150119113933  Create previsoes
up     20150119115345  Create cursos
up     20150119120602  Create curso ucs
up     20150119151914  Devise create users
up     20150119154317  Create areas
up     20150119154735  Create atribuicoes
up     20150121174741  Devise create admin users
up     20150121174822  Create active admin comments
devhost:dss jony$
```

So, what is going wrong with this?

Regards
Fabio

Comment: Why reset the database straight after migrating

Comment: Hi Frederick. My mistake, I seed the database after migration. Sorry! I've updated the post.